# Copy values with same name across classes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, reflection

I am trying to get a dialogue JSON's content and copy its properties(stored to the class Dialogues) to another class deriving from MonoBehaviour(DialogueManager).
Anyway, the GetValue method returns null even if GetProperty returns the correct propery names.
I can't just read the Json to DialogueManager, because JSONUtility apparently needs to export to a non-MonoBehaviour class.

```cs
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine;

public class DialogueManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    //999 IS RETURN TO MENU
    //1000 IS CLOSE GAME
    public static DialogueManager instance = null;
    Dialogues dial;
    public string text1 { get; set; }
    public string choices1 { get; set; }
    public string consequences1 { get; set; }
    public string text2 { get; set; }
    public string choices2 { get; set; }
    public string consequences2 { get; set; }
    public string text3 { get; set; }
    public string choices3 { get; set; }
    public string consequences3 { get; set; }
    public string text4 { get; set; }
    public string choices4 { get; set; }
    public string consequences4 { get; set; }
    public string text5 { get; set; }
    public string choices5 { get; set; }
    public string consequences5 { get; set; }
    public string text6 { get; set; }
    public string choices6 { get; set; }
    public string consequences6 { get; set; }
    public string text7 { get; set; }
    public string choices7 { get; set; }
    public string consequences7 { get; set; }
    public string text8 { get; set; }
    public string choices8 { get; set; }
    public string consequences8 { get; set; }
    public string text9 { get; set; }
    public string choices9 { get; set; }
    public string consequences9 { get; set; }
    public string text10 { get; set; }
    public string choices10 { get; set; }
    public string consequences10 { get; set; }
    public string text11 { get; set; }
    public string choices11 { get; set; }
    public string consequences11 { get; set; }
    public string text12 { get; set; }
    public string choices12 { get; set; }
    public string consequences12 { get; set; }
    public string text13 { get; set; }
    public string choices13 { get; set; }
    public string consequences13 { get; set; }
    public string text14 { get; set; }
    public string choices14 { get; set; }
    public string consequences14 { get; set; }
    public string text15 { get; set; }
    public string choices15 { get; set; }
    public string consequences15 { get; set; }
    public string text16 { get; set; }
    public string choices16 { get; set; }
    public string consequences16 { get; set; }
    public string text17 { get; set; }
    public string choices17 { get; set; }
    public string consequences17 { get; set; }
    public string text18 { get; set; }
    public string choices18 { get; set; }
    public string consequences18 { get; set; }
    public string text19 { get; set; }
    public string choices19 { get; set; }
    public string consequences19 { get; set; }
    public string text20 { get; set; }
    public string choices20 { get; set; }
    public string consequences20 { get; set; }
    public string text21 { get; set; }
    public string choices21 { get; set; }
    public string consequences21 { get; set; }
    public string text22 { get; set; }
    public string choices22 { get; set; }
    public string consequences22 { get; set; }
    public string text23 { get; set; }
    public string choices23 { get; set; }
    public string consequences23 { get; set; }
    string fixedName;

    string[] splits;
    string text;
    int[] consequences;
    private void Awake()
    {
        if(instance == null)
        {
            instance = this;
        }
        else
        {
            enabled = false;
        }
        dial = new Dialogues();
        StreamReader sR = new StreamReader(Application.dataPath + "/GameData/dialogues.json");
        string json = sR.ReadToEnd();
        dial = JsonUtility.FromJson<Dialogues>(json);
        Assign();
    }

    //This doesn't work for some reason
    public void Assign()
    {
        foreach(var property in typeof(Dialogues).GetProperties())
        {
            typeof(DialogueManager).GetProperty(property.Name).SetValue(this, property.GetValue(dial));
        }
    }
    public string GetText(int currentText)
    {
        fixedName = "text" + currentText;
        string output = typeof(DialogueManager).GetProperty(fixedName).GetValue(this, null).ToString();
        return output;
    }
    public string GetTextChoices(int textNum)
    {
        fixedName = "choices" + textNum;
        string output = typeof(DialogueManager).GetProperty(fixedName).GetValue(this, null).ToString();
        return output;
    }
    public int[] GetChoicesConsequences(int textNum)
    {
        fixedName = "consequences" + textNum;
        string output = typeof(DialogueManager).GetProperty(fixedName).GetValue(this, null).ToString();
        splits = output.Split('§');
        consequences = new int[splits.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < splits.Length; i++)
        {
            consequences[i] = int.Parse(splits[i]);
        }
        return consequences;
    }
    private void DumbAssign()
    {
        text1 = dial.text1;
        choices1 = dial.choices1;
        consequences1 = dial.consequences1;
        text2 = dial.text2;
        choices2 = dial.choices2;
        consequences2 = dial.consequences2;
        text3 = dial.text3;
        choices3 = dial.choices3;
        consequences3 = dial.consequences3;
        text4 = dial.text4;
        choices4 = dial.choices4;
        consequences4 = dial.consequences4;
        text5 = dial.text5;
        choices5 = dial.choices5;
        consequences5 = dial.consequences5;
        text6 = dial.text6;
        choices6 = dial.choices6;
        consequences6 = dial.consequences6;
        text7 = dial.text7;
        choices7 = dial.choices7;
        consequences7 = dial.consequences7;
        text8 = dial.text8;
        choices8 = dial.choices8;
        consequences8 = dial.consequences8;
        text9 = dial.text9;
        choices9 = dial.choices9;
        consequences9 = dial.consequences9;
        text10 = dial.text10;
        choices10 = dial.choices10;
        consequences10 = dial.consequences10;
        text11 = dial.text11;
        choices11 = dial.choices11;
        consequences11 = dial.consequences11;
        text12 = dial.text12;
        choices12 = dial.choices12;
        consequences12 = dial.consequences12;
        text13 = dial.text13;
        choices13 = dial.choices13;
        consequences13 = dial.consequences13;
        text14 = dial.text14;
        choices14 = dial.choices14;
        consequences14 = dial.consequences14;
        text15 = dial.text15;
        choices15 = dial.choices15;
        consequences15 = dial.consequences15;
        text16 = dial.text16;
        choices16 = dial.choices16;
        consequences16 = dial.consequences16;
        text17 = dial.text17;
        choices17 = dial.choices17;
        consequences17 = dial.consequences17;
        text18 = dial.text18;
        choices18 = dial.choices18;
        consequences18 = dial.consequences18;
        text19 = dial.text19;
        choices19 = dial.choices19;
        consequences19 = dial.consequences19;
        text20 = dial.text20;
        choices20 = dial.choices20;
        consequences20 = dial.consequences20;
        text21 = dial.text21;
        choices21 = dial.choices21;
        consequences21 = dial.consequences21;
        text22 = dial.text22;
        choices22 = dial.choices22;
        consequences22 = dial.consequences22;
    }
}

[System.Serializable]
public class Dialogues
{
    public string text1 { get; set; }
    public string choices1 { get; set; }
    public string consequences1 { get; set; }
    public string text2 { get; set; }
    public string choices2 { get; set; }
    public string consequences2 { get; set; }
    public string text3 { get; set; }
    public string choices3 { get; set; }
    public string consequences3 { get; set; }
    public string text4 { get; set; }
    public string choices4 { get; set; }
    public string consequences4 { get; set; }
    public string text5 { get; set; }
    public string choices5 { get; set; }
    public string consequences5 { get; set; }
    public string text6 { get; set; }
    public string choices6 { get; set; }
    public string consequences6 { get; set; }
    public string text7 { get; set; }
    public string choices7 { get; set; }
    public string consequences7 { get; set; }
    public string text8 { get; set; }
    public string choices8 { get; set; }
    public string consequences8 { get; set; }
    public string text9 { get; set; }
    public string choices9 { get; set; }
    public string consequences9 { get; set; }
    public string text10 { get; set; }
    public string choices10 { get; set; }
    public string consequences10 { get; set; }
    public string text11 { get; set; }
    public string choices11 { get; set; }
    public string consequences11 { get; set; }
    public string text12 { get; set; }
    public string choices12 { get; set; }
    public string consequences12 { get; set; }
    public string text13 { get; set; }
    public string choices13 { get; set; }
    public string consequences13 { get; set; }
    public string text14 { get; set; }
    public string choices14 { get; set; }
    public string consequences14 { get; set; }
    public string text15 { get; set; }
    public string choices15 { get; set; }
    public string consequences15 { get; set; }
    public string text16 { get; set; }
    public string choices16 { get; set; }
    public string consequences16 { get; set; }
    public string text17 { get; set; }
    public string choices17 { get; set; }
    public string consequences17 { get; set; }
    public string text18 { get; set; }
    public string choices18 { get; set; }
    public string consequences18 { get; set; }
    public string text19 { get; set; }
    public string choices19 { get; set; }
    public string consequences19 { get; set; }
    public string text20 { get; set; }
    public string choices20 { get; set; }
    public string consequences20 { get; set; }
    public string text21 { get; set; }
    public string choices21 { get; set; }
    public string consequences21 { get; set; }
    public string text22 { get; set; }
    public string choices22 { get; set; }
    public string consequences22 { get; set; }
    public string text23 { get; set; }
    public string choices23 { get; set; }
    public string consequences23 { get; set; }
}
```

EDIT 1: I have now edited the script to use only Dialogues class for the properties, but I still don't know how to get the properties(I need to do this in this way 'cause there will be 250+ texts)

```cs
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine;

public class DialogueManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    //999 IS RETURN TO MENU
    //1000 IS CLOSE GAME
    public static DialogueManager instance = null;
    string fixedName;
    private Dialogues dial;
    public Dialogues Dial { get { return dial; } }

    string[] splits;
    string text;
    int[] consequences;
    private void Awake()
    {
        if(instance == null)
        {
            instance = this;
        }
        else
        {
            enabled = false;
        }
        dial = new Dialogues();
        StreamReader sR = new StreamReader(Application.dataPath + "/GameData/dialogues.json");
        string json = sR.ReadToEnd();
        dial = JsonUtility.FromJson<Dialogues>(json);
    }
    public string GetText(int currentText)
    {
        fixedName = "text" + currentText;
        string output = instance.Dial.GetType().GetProperty(fixedName).GetValue(dial).ToString();
        return output;
    }
    public string GetTextChoices(int textNum)
    {
        fixedName = "choices" + textNum;
        string output = typeof(DialogueManager).GetProperty(fixedName).GetValue(this, null).ToString();
        return output;
    }
    public int[] GetChoicesConsequences(int textNum)
    {
        fixedName = "consequences" + textNum;
        string output = typeof(DialogueManager).GetProperty(fixedName).GetValue(this, null).ToString();
        splits = output.Split('§');
        consequences = new int[splits.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < splits.Length; i++)
        {
            consequences[i] = int.Parse(splits[i]);
        }
        return consequences;
    }
}

[System.Serializable]
public class Dialogues
{
    public string text1;
    public string choices1;
    public string consequences1;
    public string text2;
    public string choices2;
    public string consequences2;
    public string text3;
    public string choices3;
    public string consequences3;
    public string text4;
    public string choices4;
    public string consequences4;
    public string text5;
    public string choices5;
    public string consequences5;
    public string text6;
    public string choices6;
    public string consequences6;
    public string text7;
    public string choices7;
    public string consequences7;
    public string text8;
    public string choices8;
    public string consequences8;
    public string text9;
    public string choices9;
    public string consequences9;
    public string text10;
    public string choices10;
    public string consequences10;
    public string text11;
    public string choices11;
    public string consequences11;
    public string text12;
    public string choices12;
    public string consequences12;
    public string text13;
    public string choices13;
    public string consequences13;
    public string text14;
    public string choices14;
    public string consequences14;
    public string text15;
    public string choices15;
    public string consequences15;
    public string text16;
    public string choices16;
    public string consequences16;
    public string text17;
    public string choices17;
    public string consequences17;
    public string text18;
    public string choices18;
    public string consequences18;
    public string text19;
    public string choices19;
    public string consequences19;
    public string text20;
    public string choices20;
    public string consequences20;
    public string text21;
    public string choices21;
    public string consequences21;
    public string text22;
    public string choices22;
    public string consequences22;
    public string text23;
    public string choices23;
    public string consequences23;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I figured it out.
I changed the code to use an array of objects, with the help of JsonHelper.

Dialogues.json:

```
{
  "Items": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "text": "7:15 A.M. School starts at 8:05",
      "choices": "",
      "consequences": "2"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "text": "What do you want to do?",
      "choices": "1: Sleep for a while; 2: Get up",
      "consequences": "3?5"
    }
  ]
}
```

DialogueManager.cs:

```cs
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

public static class JsonHelper
{
    public static T[] FromJson<T>(string json)
    {
        Wrapper<T> wrapper = JsonUtility.FromJson<Wrapper<T>>(json);
        return wrapper.Items;
    }

    public static string ToJson<T>(T[] array)
    {
        Wrapper<T> wrapper = new Wrapper<T>();
        wrapper.Items = array;
        return JsonUtility.ToJson(wrapper);
    }

    public static string ToJson<T>(T[] array, bool prettyPrint)
    {
        Wrapper<T> wrapper = new Wrapper<T>();
        wrapper.Items = array;
        return JsonUtility.ToJson(wrapper, prettyPrint);
    }

    [Serializable]
    private class Wrapper<T>
    {
        public T[] Items;
    }
}

public class DialogueManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Serializable]
    public class Dialogue
    {
        public int id;
        public string text;
        public string choices;
        public string consequences;

        public Dialogue(int id, string text, string choices, string consequences)
        {
            this.id = id;
            this.text = text;
            this.choices = choices;
            this.consequences = consequences;
        }
    }

    Dialogue[] dial;
    public static DialogueManager instance = null;

    string[] splits;
    int[] consequences;
    private void Awake()
    {
        if(instance == null)
        {
            instance = this;
        }
        else
        {
            enabled = false;
        }
        StreamReader sR = new StreamReader(Application.dataPath + "/GameData/dialogues.json");
        //NON CRITTOGRAFIA
        string json = sR.ReadToEnd();
        //CRITTOGRAFIA
        //string crypted = sR.ReadToEnd();
        //string json = Encrypt.DecryptString(crypted, "think");
        dial = JsonHelper.FromJson<Dialogue>(json);
    }
    public string GetText(int currentText)
    {
        return dial[currentText - 1].text;
    }
    public string GetTextChoices(int textNum)
    {
        return dial[textNum - 1].choices;
    }
    public int[] GetChoicesConsequences(int textNum)
    {
        string output = dial[textNum - 1].consequences;
        splits = output.Split('?');
        consequences = new int[splits.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < splits.Length; i++)
        {
            consequences[i] = int.Parse(splits[i]);
        }
        return consequences;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all **do not use Properties** for the `Dialogues` class! Properties (without any backing fields) are never (de)serialized.

That is the reason why you are getting `null` from `GetValue` because the properties are never set.

Remove all `{get; set;}` and make those variables rather simple fields

```c#
public string text1;
public string choices1;
....
```

You should use properties only where you really need them - which is usually to have read only accesor properties or in order to check some values befor you get them set from external.

The same also applies to all those properties in `DialogueManager`.

---

**If** you really want to stay with properties (in `DialogueManager`) you should rather directly read from and write into the `dial` reference you have there like e.g.

```c#
public string text1 
{ 
    get { return dial.text1; }
    set { dial.text1 = value; }
}
```

---

However if you would simply make either

```c#
public Dialogues Dial;
```

or at least give it a read only property

```c#
private Dialogues dial;

public Dialogues Dial
{
    get { return dial; }
}
```

any other component could simply access those values via that field intead:

```c#
dialogueManagerReference.Dial.text1
```

and you don't need to copy any values.

Additionally if using

```c#
public Dialogues Dial;
```

or

```c#
[SerializeField] private Dialogues Dial;
```

you can also eddit/debug those values directly in the Unity Inspector.

---

And finally that data structure looks a bit odd repeating all those names and types with numbers ... I don't have your JSON file so maybe it's the way you get them but are you sure there is no List/array involved? I would rather expect a data structure here like e.g.

```c#
[Serializable]
public class Dialogues
{
    public Dialogue[] DialogueList;
}

[Serializable]
public class Dialogue
{
    public string Text;
    public string[] Choices;
    public string[] Consequences;
}
```

and the according JSON would look like e.g.

```c#
{
    "DialogueList" : [
        {
            "Text" : "some text",
            "Choices" : [
                "Option A" , "Option B", "Option C"
            ],
            "Consequences" : [
                "Good Boy!", "Oh No!", "Well maybe acceptable ..."
            ]
        },

        {
            "Text" : "some other text",
            "Choices" : [
                "Option Left" , "Option Right"
            ],
            "Consequences" : [
                "Yeay :)", "Neyy :("
            ]
        },

        ... and 21 more entries
    ]
}
```

Comment: I tried to get arrays from GetValue() before, failing. Since then, I splitted every text in 3 different properties I need :(.

Comment: If it is possible for you you should change the JSON to use Arrays. And than later access according values using the indexes like e.g. `Dial[0].Choices[2]` and not use Reflection for this .. it is very bad in performance